# Use PowerShell Invoke-Command cannot get any result

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {start-job {gsv}} -ComputerName Will
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-job} -ComputerName Will
```

Nothing was displayed. I couldn't retrieve any job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jobs are tied to the current session. The way you run `Invoke-Command` creates a new session with every invocation, so the second session naturally doesn't know anything about jobs of the first one.

Change your code to something like this, so both invocations run in the same session:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Will
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Job {gsv} }
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Job }
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thank you for your help.